# C# .NET CORE how to get the value of a custom attribute?

Tags: c#, .net-core, custom-attributes

I have a custom attribute class defined as follows.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, Inherited = false)]
internal class EncryptedAttribute : System.Attribute
{
    private bool _encrypted;
    public EncryptedAttribute(bool encrypted)
    {
        _encrypted = encrypted;
    }

    public virtual bool Encrypted
    {
        get
        {
            return _encrypted;
        }
    }
}
```

I applied the above attribute to another class as follows.

```
public class KeyVaultConfiguration
{
    [Encrypted(true)]
    public string AuthClientId { get; set; } = "";

    public string AuthClientCertThumbprint { get; set; } = "";
}
```

How do I get the value of Encrypted=True on property AuthClientId?

```
var config = new KeyVaultConfiguration();

// var authClientIdIsEncrypted = ??
```

In .NET Framework, this was easy. In .NET CORE, I think this is possible but I don't see any documentation. I believe you need to use System.Reflection but exactly how?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add `using System.Reflection` and then you may use extension methods from [CustomAttributeExtensions.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/Reflection/CustomAttributeExtensions.cs).

Something like this should work for you:

```
typeof(<class name>).GetTypeInfo()
      .GetProperty(<property name>).GetCustomAttribute<YourAttribute>();
```

in your case

```
typeof(KeyVaultConfiguration).GetTypeInfo()
      .GetProperty("AuthClientId").GetCustomAttribute<EncryptedAttribute>();
```

Comment: The link is dead.