# Pass parameter to Partial View in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0, asp.net-core-2.0

On an ASP.NET Core 2.0 application I need to render a partial view and pass a few parameters:

```
@Html.Partial("Form", new { File = "file.pdf" })
```

On the partial view I tried to access it using:

```
@Model.File
```

And I get the error:

```
RuntimeBinderException: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'File'
```

If I simply use on my partial:

```
@Model
```

I get the following printed on the page:

```
{ File = file.pdf }
```

So there the model is being passed and there is a property File in it.

So what am I missing?

Comment: Should be the same situation that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223713/can-i-pass-an-anonymous-type-to-my-asp-net-mvc-view

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You are passing untyped *(anonymous type)* data to partial view. You cannot use `@Model.File`. Instead, you will need to use ViewData's Eval method to retrieve the value.

```
@ViewData.Eval("File")
```

Traditional approach is to create a strongly typed ***ViewModel*** class, and pass it to the partial view. Then you can access it as `@Model.File`.

```
public class SampleViewModel
{
    public string File { get; set; }
}

@Html.Partial("Form", new SampleViewModel { File = "file.pdf" })
```

Inside Partial View,

```
@model SampleViewModel

<h1>@Model.File</h1>
```

Comment: Yes, I am going for the classic Model approach although not sure why the dynamic approach does not work without the ViewData.Eval

Comment: Strongly typed model is stored inside ViewData's Model. In contrast, untyped data is stored inside ViewData's Dictionary. It is why we need to use `ViewData.Eval` when retrieving data from ViewData's Dictionary.

Answer (score 6):

You should have `dynamic` as the model of your partial view, this way, you can pass everything - like your anonymous object - and it will just work. Add:

```
@model dynamic
```

To the Form.cshtml file.

Comment: I tried that and I still get the same error: RuntimeBinderException: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'File'

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong, as this is the standard way to do it. If you only need to pass the File property, why not pass that directly, e.g., @Html.Partial("Form", (object)"File.pdf") and access it directly in Model?

Comment: dynamic is used in a slightly different way. The object passed in is still of type object. Dynamic simply means that it would evaluate the type of the object in run-time. In run-time, the object will still be taken as type object.

Comment: That's not true. If you pass an anonymous object, it will be an anonymous object, and by wrapping it in a dynamic, you will be able to access its properties. The views created by the VS templates use dynamic just for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `new { File = "file.pdf" }`, you are passing an object that contains an attribute file. Since this is of type `object`, you can't access any of its variables in c# directly. There some ugly codes to access a fields from an object such as the one that can be found here: [C# .NET CORE how to get the value of a custom attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42689283/c-sharp-net-core-how-to-get-the-value-of-a-custom-attribute)

However in this case the most recommended way  (for safety) is the create a class and pass an object of that class.

So if you create the following class:

```
public class MyFileInfo{
    public string File { get; set }
}
```

Then you can create your object by passing:

```
@Html.Partial("Form", new MyFileInfo{ File = "file.pdf" })
```

In your partial view, at the beginning, define your model class

```
@model MyFileInfo
```

Then in the same file you will now be able to access

```
@Model.File
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness: you can pass arbitrary variable via a ViewDictionary

```
@Html.Partial("_Partial", model, new ViewDataDictionary(ViewData) { { "MyVarName", someValue } })
```

And then access it like this in the partial:

```
ViewData["MyVarName"]
```

Another option, you can simply set a `ViewData` var before calling the partial, and it will be passed on to it

```
@{
    ViewData["MyVarName"] = "hello";
}
@Html.Partial("_Partial", model)
```

However, strongly typed models are much easier to work with.