# How do I display a View inside another View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am practicing ASP and MVC by making a website like Twitter and I am having trouble with using a PartialView.

I have my User Home Page Controller here, which gets called from my Login Page Controller.

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    private readonly Twitter _twitter = null;
    private readonly TwitterCloneDBContext _context;
    public UserController(TwitterCloneDBContext context)
    {
        _twitter = new Twitter(context);
        _context = context;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Tweet> tweets = _twitter.TweetList();
        ViewBag.Tweets = tweets.Count;
        ViewBag.Followers = 2;
        ViewBag.Following = 3;
        return View();
    }

    public PartialViewResult TweetList()
    {
        List<Tweet> tweetList = _twitter.TweetList();
        return PartialView("TweetList",tweetList);
    }
}
```

Here is the View for it.

```
 @{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
@model IEnumerable<Tweet>

@if (Context.Session.GetString("FullName") != null)
{
    <div class="text-center">
        <h1 class="display-4">Welcome, @Context.Session.GetString("FullName")!</h1>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <div class="text-left">
                <h4>Follow</h4>
                <form asp-action="Search">
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <input type="text" name="searchName" class="form-control" placeholder="Search User" />
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <span class="text-danger">@ViewBag.SearchFail</span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h6>@ViewBag.Tweets Tweets</h6>
                <br />
                <h6>@ViewBag.Followers Followers</h6>
                <br />
                <h6>@ViewBag.Following Following</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class=border></div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <h4>Tweet your thoughts!</h4>
            <form asp-action="Tweet">
                <textarea rows="5" cols="100" name="message" class="form-control"> </textarea>
                <br />
                <input type="submit" value="Tweet" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </form>
            <span class=" text-danger">@ViewBag.ErrMessage</span>
            <div>
               @Html.PartialAsync("TwitterList",Model)            
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
else
{
    <h2>You are not Authorized!</h2>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            window.location.href = '/Home/UserLogin';
        }, 1000);
    </script>
}
```

The Partial Line is supposed to call TwitterList View which is working perfectly and displaying List as it is supposed to.

```
@model IEnumerable<TwitterClone.Models.Tweet>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.User_ID)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Message)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Created)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User_ID)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Message)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Created)
            </td>
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But when I call it using the @Html.PartialAsync() It fails by saying

```
System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=TwitterClone.Views
  StackTrace:
   at AspNetCore.Views_User_TweetList.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Cloud\source\repos\TwitterClone\TwitterClone\Views\User\TweetList.cshtml:line 19
```

and giving me this in the main page
[image: See below Tweet Button, that is my Partial View]

See below Tweet Button, that is my Partial View, if I do the Partial View any other way I get NullReferenceException in both the places. This is the closes I've gotten to this and I cannot figure it out.

**EDIT:**

My ViewBags are in another Actions that are not relevant here. They basically print an error message.

The NullExceptions are gone, my Model is not empty when I open the Table View on its own. But its empty when being called through Partial. I suspect its because something isn't being called in the chain.

If I change my Index Action to like this,

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<Tweet> tweets = _twitter.TweetList();
            ViewBag.Tweets = tweets.Count;
            ViewBag.Followers = 2;
            ViewBag.Following = 3;
            return View("Index",tweets);
        }
```

I get this error.

```
InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TwitterClone.Models.Tweet]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'TwitterClone.Models.Person'.
```

I have no Idea where ViewDataDictionary is setting Person to. The only place where I can think of that connects to UserController is my HomeController.
**EDIT**
This was a dumb mistake, I left out an @model Person in my Layout file. Sorry.
**EDIT**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
        private readonly TwitterCloneDBContext _context;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, TwitterCloneDBContext context)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _context = context;

        }

        //GET: Home/UserLogin
        public ActionResult UserLogin()
        {
            return View();
        }


        //POST: Home/UserLogin
        [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult UserLogin(Person userLogin)
        {
            var login = _context.Person.Where(a => a.UserID.Equals(userLogin.UserID)
                                              && a.Password.Equals(userLogin.Password)).FirstOrDefault();
            if (login != null)
            {
                Person session = _context.Person.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserID == userLogin.UserID);
                session.Active = 1;
                HttpContext.Session.SetString("FullName", login.FullName);
                HttpContext.Session.SetString("UserID", login.UserID);
                _context.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "User");
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.ErrMsg = "Invalid Credentials";
                return View();
            }           
        }
}
```

And its View

```
@model Person
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "UserLogin";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/LoginLayout.cshtml";
}

<h1>Welcome!</h1>

<h4>Enter Credentials</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="UserLogin">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="UserID" class="control-label">User ID</label>
                <input asp-for="UserID" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="UserID" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Password" class="control-label">Password</label>
                <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>   
</div>

<div>
    New User? <a asp-action="Signup">Signup</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass parameter to Partial View in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46100200/pass-parameter-to-partial-view-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: @yogihosting Looks like ViewData.Evail is for single item strings. I am working with Lists so I don't think it answers it. Unless there are other ways to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is

```
<span class="text-danger">@ViewBag.SearchFail</span>
```

I can't see ViewBag.SearchFail or ViewBag.ErrMessage in your action.

You have a big bug. Move redirect from Index view to action, otherwise it will be always running after creating the page.

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
      if (Context.Session.GetString("FullName") != null)
        {
 
        List<Tweet> tweets = _twitter.TweetList();
         .....
       
        return View("Index", tweets);
       }
         RedirectToAction("Login", "Users")
    }
```

Since you are using the same model for both, try to replace

```
    @Html.PartialAsync("TwitterList",Model)
```

with

```
    <partial name="TwitterList" />
```

and fix the model of both views

```
@model List<TwitterClone.Models.Tweet>
```

also fix the partial view

```
@if(@Model!=null && Model.Count >0)
{
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].User_ID)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].Message)
            </th>
          ......
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am getting the same NullReferenceExceptions in both views now,

Comment: @Cloud I updated the answer. Pls try again.

Comment: Null reference can't go throw partial view since  you should have already added to your code" if (@Model!=null)"

Comment: Sorry, what I wanted to say was that my Model.Tweet (in my SQLDB) is filled with Data yet it's showing up as Null in model. Even though the controller is passing the list.

Comment: Changing the Index Action results in this: `InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List 1[TwitterClone.Models.Tweet]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'TwitterClone.Models.Person'.` I wanted to avoid this error so I was going in a roundabout way of doing this. I have no idea where this Models.Person is being set.

Comment: You should post List<Tweet> tweets = _twitter.TweetList(); if you have a problem with an empty model

Comment: @Cloud I updated my answer again. Move redirect from view to action.